# Integrating $\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos x }{x^2}dx$ via contour integral.

Tags: complex-analysis

In Stein's Complex Analysis notes, the following exampleis given.

[image]

They then proceed to calculate the integral over the small semicircle.

My question is, why is it necessary to dodge the origin? Afterall, the singularity at $z=0$ is removable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The singularity is removable for the function you want to integrate but not for their $f(z).$

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: $f(z)$ has a pole at the origin, since the imaginary part is $\sin(z)/z^2$

Comment: By $f(z)$ you mean $\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}$? But then, if one replaces the original integrand by $\frac{1}{2} \frac{\sin^2 (x/2)}{x^2}$, and considers $f(z)= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\sin^2 z}{z^2}$, it is no longer singular, or?

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about. The function DOES have an actual pole at $0.$  It is conceivable that there is some way to do the contour integral without cutting out zero, but that's not the way Stein et al are doing it...

Comment: I don't see why $f(z)= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\sin^2 (z/2)}{z^2}$ has a pole at zero. Isn't it just a removable singularity?

Comment: It does not have a pole at zero, but that's not the function we are talking about.

Comment: Would it not work if we consider that function instead then?

Comment: Be my guest, if you can compute the integral with it. You had asked why they chose the contour, and it is because they have to *with the function they chose.*

Answer (score 5):

The motivation for the question seems to be: Why does the author integrate $f(z)=(1-e^{iz})/z^2$ over the complex plane, rather than the original integrand $g(z)=(1-\cos z)/z^2$ ? You're right that $g$ is an entire function, and it could be integrated over a semicircle without having to dodge the origin.

However, the integral of $g$ over the arc $\gamma_R^+$ doesn't obey a nice bound.
While integrating $f$, the author needs the inequality
$$
\left|\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}\right|\leq\frac{2}{|z|^2},
$$
which is justified by the fact that $|e^{iz}|\leq 1$ for $z$ in the upper half-plane. The same can't be said for $\cos z=(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})/2$; instead, the $e^{-iz}$ term is large in the upper half-plane. That's why $g$ is less convenient than $f$.

Answer (score 0):

We can evaluate the integral using Feynman's trick:

$$ I = \int_0^\infty \frac{1 - \cos(x)}{x^2}dx = I(1) $$

$$ I(a)= \int_0^\infty \frac{1 - \cos(ax)}{x^2}dx $$

$$ \frac{dI(a)}{da}= \int_0^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial a} \Bigg(\frac{1 - \cos(ax)}{x^2}\Bigg)dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(ax)}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

$$ I(a) = \frac{\pi}{2}a+C_1 $$
$$ I(0) = 0 = 0+C_1 \to C_1 = 0 $$
$$ I = I(1) = \frac{\pi}{2} $$