# Where is the "⨓" integral symbol defined?

Tags: integration

I have been trying to find a definition for this symbol but so far I have found nothing. Is there some esoteric text that uses it?

Below is a page about the Unicode character for the symbol.

'LINE INTEGRATION WITH SEMICIRCULAR PATH AROUND POLE' (U+2A13)
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2a13/index.htm

Given the Unicode description above of the character, it seems reasonably that the symbol has some relation to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem . However that page doesn't define the symbol, and I haven't been able to find the symbol defined elsewhere. That's why I think it might exist in some esoteric text.

Comment: We need to know your background to provide a suitable answer. Do you know complex analysis?

Comment: @Chappers Yes I know complex analysis.

Comment: You have a lot of them http://graphemica.com/%E2%A8%93 clicking the arrows...

Comment: @RafaBudría Yea there are a lot of them there. I was assuming that because they exist there is probably some mathematical definition of the symbols somewhere

Comment: Only to hypothesize, maybe the symbol creators, whoever they could be, defined them in the possibility that somebody find them useful...

Comment: @RafaBudría That sounds plausible to me. I hope I can find a definition of it somewhere, or some explanation why there is no definition, if there is none.

Comment: Presumably, then, it is used when there is a pole on the integration contour, to write it in terms of integrals without singularities, such as in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/594350/221811). I doubt it's ever actually used, though: the fanciest integral signs most people use are $\iint$, $\oint$ and their friends and occasionally an integral with a bar through it for principal value (surprisingly not available in latex without some work).

Comment: You can just use a simple integration sign and clarify whatever you want to clarify with words.

Comment: you have to look very carefully to distinguish $⨓$ and $⨔$