# Help with understanding evaluation of a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

In this post - [Integrating $\int_0^\infty \frac{1-\cos x }{x^2}dx$ via contour integral.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/594350/integrating-int-0-infty-frac1-cos-x-x2dx-via-contour-integral) - I understood upto the point where $|\frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2}| \leq \frac{2}{|z^2|}$. I didn't understand the next sentence equating $\int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{1-e^{x^2}}{x^2} dx$.

I think it should be 1/2 the quantity on the right, since there are two values of $\int_{|x|>\epsilon} \frac{1-e^{x^2}}{x^2} dx$ in the original equation. Can someone explain this?

I am doing a self-study of complex-analysis by Shakarchi.

Comment: All they are doing is to let $R \to \infty$ in the previous equation.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy can you be more specific? There are two integrals where the integrand is $\frac{1-e^{ix}}{x^2}$. One goes from -R to $-\epsilon$ and the other goes from $\epsilon$ to R.

Comment: If you add the integral from $-\infty$ to $-\epsilon$ and the integral from $\epsilon$ to $\infty$ you get the integral over $|x| \geq \epsilon$.

Comment: Thank you @KaviRamaMurthy! I have one more question in the same problem - $\int_{\gamma \epsilon +} \frac{1-e^{iz}}{z^2} $ -> $\int_{0}^{\pi} ii d\theta$ where $z=e^{i\theta}$ and $dz=i\epsilon e^{i \theta d\theta}$. How?or how does $1-e^{iz}$ = i